# Apache Internal Server Error with just [:error] [pid #] 1.0 # in error_log

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm having Apache serve a Flask app via mod_wsgi.

The app is a web form that saves fields to a local file on form submission. Everything runs smoothly other than occasionally on hitting the form submission the server throws an Internal Server error. Also so far I haven't seen anything actually written to file - even when the form submission succeeds without the Internal Server error. I am suspecting its something to do with file write permissions.

The only entries in the error_log don't shed any light, at least to my untrained eye:

> [Tue May 26 22:35:46.401070 2015] [:error] [pid 28335] 1.0 1
>   [Tue May 26 22:37:33.313577 2015] [:error] [pid 28339] 1.0 1
>   [Tue May 26 22:38:21.074149 2015] [:error] [pid 28336] 1.0 1
>   [Tue May 26 22:46:04.284230 2015] [:error] [pid 28338] 1.0 2
>   [Tue May 26 22:46:04.291985 2015] [:error] [pid 28340] 1.0 2

Any suggestions on what I should do to further narrow down the investigation?

I've tried disabling the local file save temporarily and it did seem to remove the problem (no Internal Server error occurrences when the write to file code is commented out, whereas at least 1 in 10 iterations will get the Internal Server error when the write to file code is uncommented).

The python code that writes to file is simply a call to the following:

```
def logtofile(text):
    with open("usagelogs.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(text)
    return
```

As mentioned above, I've been unable to see any signs of this writing actually happening - though I have to admit I am also unsure where the file will be written to (will it be in the same path as the .py file, or somewhere else?)

The code runs fine when I run it on my localhost (non-production web server).

On the production environment I'm running:
  Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

---

Update based on comments received so far:

Changing the file path (as below) did remove the Internal Server error, but I still can't locate where logs.txt is actually stored. Any hints?

```
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file = os.path.join(dir,'logs.txt')

def logtofile(text):
    with open(file, "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(text)
    return
```

---

Update 2

This is now resolved as follows:

1. Modified User and Group as defined [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/#configuring-apache).
2. Established that the file was being saved as /var/www/html//logs.txt
3. chowned the file by the User and Group defined in 1.

Comment: You could try using an absolute path

Comment: For reason for absolute path see http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory Also read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Access_Rights_Of_Apache_User about permissions.

Comment: Thanks both for setting me on the right path (pun intended)! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved as follows:

1. Modified User and Group as defined [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/#configuring-apache).
2. Established that the file was being saved as `/var/www/html/<app name>/logs.txt`
3. chowned the file by the User and Group defined in 1.